# Does the git abbreviated SHA-1 hash expand automatically when using %h in format?

Tags: git

I know that the following will auto expand the SHA-1 hash because the git documentation says so:

```
git log --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline
```

But does the following also expand the sha hash printed if there are more than one hashes with the same first 7 characters?

```
 git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h"
```

Even though the above outputs only the most recent commit, I am hoping that it makes sure the short SHA-1 hash is as long as necessary to be unique within all the commits of the local repository.  Is this true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it prints an unambiguous abbreviation of each SHA-1, using more than 7 characters if necessary.

The git repo for git itself, `git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git`, currently has 4 pairs of commits with the same 7-digit SHA-1 hash:

```
191f24171718e894cb5ba806bc45861ebac95e96
191f241b528c10e242d045bde2cef70fb013a6e5

2e6e3e829f3759823d70e7af511bc04cd05ad0af
2e6e3e82ee36b3e1bec1db8db24817270080424e

3b130ade45c70af63c7692387b65f161770a8ccc
3b130adf9c8b0b37acb0959b84a3222bc22ebcff

d53a35020d380c199b010c9884ab15995f8e982b
d53a35032a67fde5b59c8a6a66e0466837cbaf1e
```

Behold:

```
$ git log -a --pretty=format:%h%n | egrep '398dd4b|d53a350'
398dd4b
d53a3503
d53a3502
$
```

As you can see, it prints a 7-digit abbreviation for commit

```
398dd4bd039680ba98497fbedffa415a43583c16
```

(which happens to be the most recent commit on the `master` branch at the moment), but 8-digit abbreviations for the commits

```
d53a35020d380c199b010c9884ab15995f8e982b
d53a35032a67fde5b59c8a6a66e0466837cbaf1e
```

(for which a 7-character abbreviation would be ambiguous).

(The previous version of this answer mentioned that an ambiguous 7-character abbreviation given on the command line, as in `git log -n 1 d53a350`, produces an error message. This is correct, but it doesn't answer the actual question.)